# Ruby: Transfer text from one file to another but unintentionally converts to Chinese?

Tags: ruby

So I was doing this as part of Learn Ruby the Hard Way Exercise 17 Study Drill 2. This was intended to open one .txt file, transfer the contents to the following .txt file.

test.rb 
In command line I put: ruby test.rb testa.txt testb.txt

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV

open(from_file) do |f|
  var = f.read
  puts var
  open(to_file, "w"){|t| t.write(var)}
end
```

testa.txt

```
This is a test 
This becomes Chinese no matter what
This is English again
This becomes Chinese again
```

testb.txt (This is what becomes of it after running: ruby test.rb testa.txt testb.txt in command line)

```
This is a test 
਍吀栀椀猀 戀攀挀漀洀攀猀 䌀栀椀渀攀猀攀 渀漀 洀愀琀琀攀爀 眀栀愀琀ഀഀ
This is English again
਍吀栀椀猀 戀攀挀漀洀攀猀 䌀栀椀渀攀猀攀 愀最愀椀渀
```

It always produces Chinese every 2nd line. I don't even have Chinese on my language preference, just English (Canada) and English (United States). Would really appreciate it if anyone can help decipher what's causing all this. Couldn't find anything in the ruby documentation :/

Comment: Are you sure it is Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer is probably being inserted into a character/byte (8 bits make 1 byte) somewhere along the process. That is, into an actual character.